# Grant Standard user to run one EXE file as an Admin using GPO

Tags: windows-server-2008, administrator, group-policy, elevation

I have a domain in Server 2008 where we use a certain program which updates periodically. The domain users do not have any kind of Domain admin or local admin privileges. I would like to create a GPO so that the "update.exe" file for that particular program runs as an admin without asking for admin password on all the computers for all the users. Is there a way for me to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how you can use a group policy, to run a program as an Administrator, when a user logs into the domain?

Comment: I am asking how do I set the program to install and update automatically with admin rights for a domain user(who does not have any admin rights) with the help of group policy

Comment: [Can I Deploy a batch file with Group Policy to run as administrator?](https://serverfault.com/questions/644801/can-i-deploy-a-batch-file-with-group-policy-to-run-as-administrator).  You would run the script each time they log into the domain.  How you write the script to launch the installer as another user is a different problem all together though.

Comment: You can actually just deploy software also [How to Deploy Software Using Group Policy](http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/windows/2006/11/14/how-to-deploy-software-using-group-policy.html) through a group policy then forcefully do a group policy update on your clients.  I suggest using the script you read about earlier to do this.

Comment: But how will it install the software if the user does not have any admin rights? Either it will give them a "Access is denied" error or it will ask them for an Admin password. In both the cases, the administrator have to intervene, which is what we are trying to avoid

Comment: Most update mechanisms do not run the software in the logged on users context. They are generally given admin credentials/permissions of their own and use these. I highly suggest you read up on this subject to understand it better.

Comment: I linked you to documentation instead of answering this question for several reasons.  The first reason, is I know nothing about your infrastructure, except your using a Windows Server 2008 DC The second reason is there are multiple ways to skin this cat, so I provided you research, so you can ask how to skin the cat a specific way.  Third reason, is that it appears you need to do a tad bit more research on the subject, if you are asking "how do I install the software as an administrator" when I indicated a script that does that is it's own question (which has a duplicate).

Comment: @Ramhound: I know how to install a software as an admin. What I was asking is how can I install a software (or run a .exe file) for a domain user if they don't have admin rights, using GPO, without admin intervention? I will read the link that you have attached and will see if I can find something similar to my current situation.

Comment: If you had read the link, before you asked the follow-up question, you wouldn't have asked the follow-up question.  I hope you can see how it might be discouraging to go to the effort of finding several related links, and then being asked about information, that was contained in those links.